# Left join IS NULL

Tags: mysql

Is there a possibility to filter with IS NULL and another variable?

`table1.id | table1.product | table2.product_id | table2.attribute_id
1 | Product 1 | 1 | 1
1 | Product 1 | 1 | NULL
1 | Product 1 | 1 | 3
2 | Product 2 | 2 | NULL
2 | Product 2 | 2 | 2
2 | Product 2 | 2 | 3
3 | Product 3 | 3 | 1
3 | Product 3 | 3 | 2
3 | Product 3 | 3 | NULL`

So, I would like to filter products with no attribute_id 1 and 2.

Comment: Yes. What have you tried ?

Comment: SELECT table1.product FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.product_id WHERE (table2.attribute_id='1' AND count(table1.id) IS NULL) || (table2.attribute_id='2' AND count(table1.id) IS NULL)

Comment: Why do you use count ?

Comment: Good question ;-) I've tried it also without the 'count' statement, but I think the problem is that only rows with the attribute_id 1 or 2 are selected and since there are no rows in table2, there isn't selected anything.

Comment: What is it you are trying to actually do? You are using a LEFT OUTER JOIN, so assuming the id field cannot be null then there should never be a matched record on table 2 returned that isn't in table 1

Comment: That's correct, but what are the other possibilities toe select the rows without a left join match?

Comment: In that case it isn't a LEFT JOIN, rather a RIGHT JOIN if you want the r/h table whether the left one is there or not. But if you want from both irrespective of whether the other has a match then that is a full outer join which mysql does not support. Could you paste a few sample rows from table1 and table2, along with the results you want for those rows?